# Alternative to jQuery .append on SVG Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mxgraph

I'm currently using mxGraph's mxClient.js to generate my flowchart graph using a series of `graph.insertVertex` and `graph.insertEdge`.

I tried to `.append` a `div` that would float over nodes with a jQuery `.mouseover()` event that has the following method inside: `$(theNode).append(<div>hello</div>)` but it fails to work.

However, I'm currently able to attach a `console.log` event whenever the `.mouseover` event occurs and also when there is a `.mouseout` event. How come only certain DOM interactions work with SVG?

Comment: Please make your question readable by using formatting. Especially `<tags>` need to be handled correctly otherwise they are not visible.

Comment: Thanks, do you have the link to the formatting page for stack?

Comment: @Xenyal: There's an entire toolbar at your disposal when you're asking or editing (or answering or editing an answer), as well as a tempting `[?]` button... When asking, at least part of the time, there's also a big orange **How to Format** box with bullet items in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery that adds support for SVG elements.

[jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Comment: I've looked at it and there seems to be many issues; simply loading the jquery.svg.js and jquery.svgdom.js files into my project produces a jQuery is not defined `ReferenceError`. I already have jQuery 1.11.1 so the dependency should be satisfied no?

Comment: Are you including jQuery before jQuery.svg?

Comment: That fixed it. How come basic functionality like `$("#svgContainer").svg('get');` returns `undefined` in the console?